# Converting Web App into Native App for android using phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, web-applications, mobile, cordova

Is it possible to convert a web app into native app for Android using PhoneGap and jQuery mobile? If so, please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**. Every app developed using **PhoneGap** is automatically converted to a native one upon building. You can use **Eclipse** for your development purposes or use **Phonegap's build service** to get your app.

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
>   applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app
>   stores.

You can access the PhoneGap build service through
https://build.phonegap.com/

[UPDATED] You can use jquery, sencha or possibly any such frameworks for building an app with phonegap.

Comment: Haha. That's the second time my answer was unmarked as answer.

Comment: sorry AndersDaniel and Nikhil.Actually I am a newbie to stack overflow.so only i misunderstood the feature.

Comment: Is there any guide to create a responsive webapp that compatible to phonegap? I use twitter-bootstrap for responsiveness and http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ for mobile menu.

Comment: @Kiddo Perhaps you could look into jQuery Mobile

Comment: Sorry. I mean to convert a responsive website to phonegap (android native app). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's the whole idea of PhoneGap.

Have you tried using this?
http://phonegap.com/start#android

I use it myself and have very little trouble with it.

Edit: I have also tried using PhoneGap Build as Nikhil suggested, and that will work just as fine. But if you want to understand what happens I believe Eclipse is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil and Anders.It was very useful.I have tried a sample app using phonegap and jquery mobile.I have another doubt.I wish to create a mobile web site using jquery mobile.Is it possible to convert that also to native android app using phonegap?

Comment: Yes, there should be no problem in that. In Eclipse, if you decide to use that, you can reference jquery mobile and use it like in any other site. Also be sure to check out http://phonegap.com/tools where you can find a lot of cool tools to use together with PhoneGap. I'm sure some of them will have focus on jQuery mobile.